# Convert csv to xlsb from Linux Server

Tags: excel, linux, bash, powershell, csv

I have a client who is wanting a rather large report ran that returns the results in csv format. However they are unable to open the .csv because the row count is too high. We found that we are able to import the csv into MSaccess and then load that database into excel.

However I am looking for a solution that will allow me to convert the .csv to xlsb from the linux server that this report is running on. I did some searching around and haven't found anything fruitful.

I tried using a Powershell script to perform the conversion however the file is still to large to, and the PC runs out of resources when attempting to make the conversion.

```
#Define locations and delimiter
$csv = "source.csv" #Location of the source file
$xlsx = "output.xlsx" #Desired location of output
$delimiter = "," #Specify the delimiter used in the file

# Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

# Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)
$excel.Quit()
```

I am open to any and all solutions that may help automate this process.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you want this question to keep going, edit it and paste in the PowerShell code you are trying to make work, along with any output. This is how SO works. https://stackoverflow.com/help